# Библиотека date.js: вывод формата даты

Tags: дата, php, html, javascript

Есть библиотека [datejs](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/APIDocumentation). Вопрос: как вывести месяц по русски (пример: ноябрь или ноября)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

А открыть исходный код сложно? На первой же строке:

```
Date.CultureInfo={name:"en-US",englishName:"English (United States)",nativeName:"English (United States)",dayNames:["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"],abbreviatedDayNames:["Sun","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat"],shortestDayNames:["Su","Mo","Tu","We","Th","Fr","Sa"],firstLetterDayNames:["S","M","T","W","T","F","S"],monthNames:["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"],abbreviatedMonthNames:["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"],...
```

Берем и переводим..)

**UPDATE**

Совсем для ленивых перевел месяца...)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="date.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript"><!--
    Date.CultureInfo["monthNames"] = ["Января","Февраля","Марта","Апреля","Мая","Июня","Июля","Августа","Сентября","Октября","Ноября","Декабря"];
    data = Date.today().toString("d-MMMM-yyyy");
    alert(data);
// --></script>
```